# How can I replace a character in a string with something else?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I'm making a program. Now to write the data in the file I need to replace the spaces in the string obtained with lets say a `#` symbol.

Is there any command in C# that lets me do this without looping through the whole string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, use the `Replace()` method.

```
s = s.Replace(" ", "#");
```

(And if you want people here to want to help you in the future, my recommendation would be to start accepting some answers. Just a thought.)

Answer (score 0):

To replace # with text

```
string s = "test # again";
s = s.Replace("#", "Superman");
```

To replace *space* with another character

```
string s = "test again";
s = s.Replace(' ', '#');
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to retrieve the returned string from the Replace() method as it won't change the original string...it generates a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [`Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) of the `string` object. This will do the trick:

```
string newString = oldString.Replace(" ", "#");
```