# Remove White Space Characters From String

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace

String variable stores value as like  .. `careteam order 4-26-11.csv`

i need to trim the value .. in c# as like  `careteamorder4-26-11.csv`  - by removing the space ..!

how to remove empty space in the string variable ?

Comment: As pointed out below, "trim" is for removing white space on the front and/or end of your text value.  Use "replace" to remove white space from anywhere in your string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace a character in a string with something else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242323/how-can-i-replace-a-character-in-a-string-with-something-else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public string RemoveSpaceAfter(string inputString)
    {
        try
        {


            string[] Split = inputString.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
            //SHOW RESULT
            for (int i = 0; i < Split.Length; i++)
            {
                fateh += Convert.ToString(Split[i]);
            }
            return fateh;
        }
        catch (Exception gg)
        {
            return fateh;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 44):

```
string trimmed = "careteam order4-26-11.csv".Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I would recommend .Replace(" ",String.Empty);

Comment: Note that String.Replace returns the result of the replace operation; it doesn't actually mutate the string it's called on.

Comment: @softwaredeveloper: Why?  I use `String.Empty` as well, but honestly there is no good reason to prefer one over the other as long as you're consistent.

Comment: I've used `""` and `String.Empty` interchangably - is there a difference?

Comment: `String.Empty = ""`, there is no difference.

Comment: There is no technical difference between `""` and `string.Empty`, but I think there is a readability difference. `" "` and `""` look much more alike than `" "` and `string.Empty`, so I personally read and understand the code quicker with `string.Empty` in this case.

Comment: @all because it is more readable. It can be hard to spot " " a single space and no space in the default Visual Studio Font. Just my experience. (Also technically please do read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx) to appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @software that depends. Jon Skeet prefers to use `""` (check the link I've posted previously in the comments)

Comment: @software: That blog link puts cold water on your suggestion.